# Custom UITableViewController inside Container View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard, uicontainerview

I am trying to insert a custom UITableViewController inside a Container View. The Container View is placed inside a cell of a static UITableView as shown in the figure below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A762B.png

I simply want a method to combine static with dynamic cells in the same screen.

In the Identity Inspector when the field Class is empty (i.e. a standard UITableViewController) it works showing an empty dynamic table inside the cell. But when I put my custom class name (that extends UITableViewController) in that field I get a NSInternalInconsistencyException:

```
[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "Enx-aT-Rum-view-zY2-9U-Z6d" nib but didn't get a UITableView.
```

These are the contents of MyCustomUITableViewController:

```
@implementation MyCustomUITableViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}
@end
```

I have to admit that I still don't understand all the logic behind Container View, but I just want to show only one view inside (not doing any swapping or else).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let me point out the issues here first-

Problem 1: you can not have an controller inside another controller. That means, inside your Static tableview, you can not have a dynamic tableview Controller.

Solution 1:You can have a dynamic TableView.

Problem 2: You can not have a static Tableview inside a View Controller. If you want a Static Tableview then you need to have a UITableViewController rather than the UIViewController.

Solution 2: You just need to delete the ViewController you have and replace with a UITableViewController.

Now to achieve one controller where you can have a dynamic TableView inside a static tableview, you will need to implement you dynamic table's datasource inside the Static Table's ViewController which would be a very bad practise. 
The static table should not need to know anything about your dynamic Table, at least about the data that will be populated in your dynamic table. However, if you want a dynamic tableview inside your static tableView then your static tableview's controller needs to implement the UITableViewDatasource.

[image]
So, you may want to re-think about the structure.